# Automatically escape string in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a string: `✪EagerWarriors -`  which I would like to escape automatically in js, becuase whenever I try to print that in a canvas it goes like this:
`âœªEagerWarriors - ð–Žð–’ð–’ð–”ð–—ð–™ð–†ð–‘ð–‹ð–”ð–—ð–™ð–šð–“ð–Š` So how do I make it so it escapes to `✪EagerWarriors -` ?

```
function draw(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50,50,50)";
     ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";

     ctx.fillRect(10, 10, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('avatar'), 20, 20);

     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(51,153,255)";
     ctx.fillText('✪EagerWarriors - ', 10, 40);
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(50, 50, 50)";
}
```

This goes for everywhere! Not only in canvas, but default HTML. This will not be used in HTML but I had to test if this error only occured in js, but seems like it has something to do with it's encoding!

> This will be done in node.js!

Comment: is your file encoded in utf-8 ? have you also set the meta tag charset to utf-8 (e.g. `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the head part) ?

Comment: @ValLeNain Can't set Meta-tag to utf8 in node.js cause no html... But can try using their library to encode it?

Comment: my bad I didn't see it was for Node. And I don't really know Node :)

Comment: Turned out to be worse: `Ã¢ÅÂªEagerWarriors - Ã°ÂâÅ½Ã°ÂââÃ°ÂââÃ°ÂââÃ°ÂââÃ°Âââ¢Ã°Âââ Ã°ÂââÃ°Âââ¹Ã°ÂââÃ°ÂââÃ°Âââ¢Ã°ÂâÅ¡Ã°ÂââÃ°ÂâÅ `

Comment: Is this useful? `%C3%A2%C5%93%C2%AAEagerWarriors%20-%20%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%C5%BD%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%99%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%99%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%9D%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%94%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%84%A2%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%A0%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%98%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%B9%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%9D%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%94%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%84%A2%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%C5%A1%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%E2%80%9C%C3%B0%C2%9D%E2%80%93%C5%A0`

Comment: Not sure about nodejs, but strings in Javascript are UTF-16 encoded. You'll probably need to convert from your input charset with something like https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite. Also reading this might help http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: "It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses." https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/